# Implement copy-on-write idiom in MyVector

Tags: c++, vector, copy-on-write

I have my class which stores a  collection of objects with their names

```
template <typename T>
class MyVector
{
private:
    vector<T> objects;
    vector<string> m_names;
    size_t m_ref_ptr;
public:
    MyVector()
    {
        m_ref_ptr = 1;
    }

    MyVector(const MyVector& other) : objects(other.objects),
                                        m_ref_ptr(other.m_ref_ptr),
                                        m_names(other.m_names)
    {
        m_ref_ptr++;
    }
    void push_back(const T& obj, const std::string& name)
    {
        copy_names();
        objects.push_back(obj);
        m_names.push_back(name);
    }
void copy_names()
{
    if (m_ref_ptr == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    size_t temp_ref_ptr = 1;
    vector<string> temp_names(m_names);
    m_ref_ptr--;
    m_ref_ptr = temp_ref_ptr;
    m_names = temp_names;
}
```

The task is to use copy-on-write idiom for names for efficiency.
I tried something, but I am not sure why do we need this, if everything works okay in my class without this copy-on-write, I read about this idiom: the main idea is:  we create real copy when we want to write something, with purpose to write. 
My code is really simple. Please, give me a tipe how to do this in my code?

Comment: Use a `std::shared_ptr` to own the `m_names` collection.  When you write to `m_names` before the write happens clone it into a new collection owned by a new std::shared_ptr, then do the write.  You will have to ensure that you do not leak any references to the underlying collection so all updates will have to be through method(s) you implement.

Comment: thanks for answer, you said that "before the write happens clone it into a new collection owned by a new std::shared_ptr, then do the write."
Is this okay if this new collection with shared_ptr will be declared only in function copy_names() like in code now ?

Comment: No, the class member `vector<string> m_names;` need to be changed to 
 `std::shared_ptr<vector<string>> m_cow_names;`  (cow - copy on write).

Comment: yes, this I understood. I am sorry but I really do not understand what I have to write in method copy_names() which calls in push_back function.
It seems to me that this method does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can not add to the comments because I don't have enough reputation points yet, so I write this as answer:

Given *m_names* is a *std::shared_ptr*,  in *copy_names* (and assuming *using namespace std* you write:

```
if (m_names.use_count() > 1) { // this is c++11
    m_names = make_shared<vector<string>>(*m_names); 
}
```

You can drop the *m_ref_ptr* member, because *std::shared_ptr* will keep track of this. In the constructor will have to create an empty vector:

```
MyVector()
{
    m_names = make_shared<vector<string>>()); 
}
```

BTW, in your code the *m_ref_ptr* was not changing the reference count in the original object, i.e. if you would have done:

```
MyVector  a; 
...
MyVector b = a;
```

then you would still have *a.m_ref_ptr == 1*. *std::shared_ptr* takes properly care of this.